# how do i solve this undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass and call the result in the template file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table that has so much data (transactions data) I want to make comprehensive report on. This table has `Currency`, `Fee charged`, `Network Fee Charged`, `Order Type`,`Created_at`, `Updated_at`. For example, in this report I like to calculate sum of `fees` based on the datetime range chosen and if no datetime chosen, default to 30 days and calculate sum of fees based all unique currencies on the database table.

In achieving this, **this is what I have done** which doesn't work, but runs into `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Error ``.

```
module Admin
  module Statistic
    class RevenuesController < BaseController
      def show
        @revenues_grid = ::Statistic::RevenuesGrid.new(params[:statistic_revenues_grid])
        @revenues_reports = []
        Currency.all.each do |currency|
          start_datetime = params.nil? ? 30.days.ago : params[:created_at][0] # This throws the error
          end_datetime = params.nil? ? Time.now : params[:created_at][1] # This throws the error too
          revenues_report_for_currency = get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
          @revenues_reports << revenues_report_for_currency
        end
      end

      def get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
        total_withdraw_fees_charged = Withdraw.where(:currency => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_withdraw_network_fees_charged= 0.3 * total_withdraw_fees_charged
        net_income_from_withdraws = total_withdraw_fees_charged - total_withdraw_network_fees_charged

        total_sell_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderAsk', :bid => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_buy_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderBid', :ask => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_trading_fees = total_sell_order_fees_charged + total_buy_order_fees_charged

        total_fees = net_income_from_withdraws + total_trading_fees

        {
          :total_withdraw_fees_charged =>  total_withdraw_fees_charged,
          :total_withdraw_network_fees_charged =>  total_withdraw_network_fees_charged,
          :net_income_from_withdraws =>  net_income_from_withdraws,
          :total_sell_order_fees_charged =>  total_sell_order_fees_charged,
          :total_buy_order_fees_charged =>  total_buy_order_fees_charged,
          :total_trading_fees =>  total_trading_fees,
          :total_fees => total_fees
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

1. How do I solve this `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Error ``?

Comment: What are the `params` that the method received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `params.nil?` in the line `start_datetime = params.nil? ? 30.days.ago : params[:created_at][0]`

To be `params[:created_at].nil?`

You Code after change will be:

```
module Admin
  module Statistic
    class RevenuesController < BaseController
      def show
        @revenues_grid = ::Statistic::RevenuesGrid.new(params[:statistic_revenues_grid])
        @revenues_reports = []
        Currency.all.each do |currency|
          start_datetime = params[:created_at].nil? ? 30.days.ago : params[:created_at][0] # This shouldn't throw error
          end_datetime = params[:created_at].nil? ? Time.now : params[:created_at][1] # This shouldn't throw error
          revenues_report_for_currency = get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
          @revenues_reports << revenues_report_for_currency
        end
      end

      def get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
        total_withdraw_fees_charged = Withdraw.where(:currency => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_withdraw_network_fees_charged= 0.3 * total_withdraw_fees_charged
        net_income_from_withdraws = total_withdraw_fees_charged - total_withdraw_network_fees_charged

        total_sell_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderAsk', :bid => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_buy_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderBid', :ask => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_trading_fees = total_sell_order_fees_charged + total_buy_order_fees_charged

        total_fees = net_income_from_withdraws + total_trading_fees

        {
          :total_withdraw_fees_charged =>  total_withdraw_fees_charged,
          :total_withdraw_network_fees_charged =>  total_withdraw_network_fees_charged,
          :net_income_from_withdraws =>  net_income_from_withdraws,
          :total_sell_order_fees_charged =>  total_sell_order_fees_charged,
          :total_buy_order_fees_charged =>  total_buy_order_fees_charged,
          :total_trading_fees =>  total_trading_fees,
          :total_fees => total_fees
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

A better approach is to replace

```
start_datetime = params[:created_at].nil? ? 30.days.ago : params[:created_at][0]
end_datetime = params[:created_at].nil? ? Time.now : params[:created_at][1]
```

with

```
start_datetime, end_datetime = params[:created_at].nil? ? [30.days.ago, Time.now] : params[:created_at]
```

Comment: but where does the `30.days.ago` go when I do this?

Comment: I update the code snippet you provide with my answer. @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi